# Many to many with extra column only returns one row

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have `Order's` which consist of a bunch of `Product's` and a quantity.

My `Order` entity:

```
@Entity(name = "orders") // Select * from order order by... NO!
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = EAGER)
    private List<OrderEntity> orderEntities = new ArrayList<>();
...
```

The relation between `orders` and `products` is as follows:

```
@Entity
public class OrderEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    private Order order;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = EAGER)
    private Product product;

    private int quantity;
...
```

My `product` is as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<OrderEntity> orderEntity;
...
```

The problem is that when I select an `order` by it's `id` I only get one `OrderEntity` back even though I can see that there are several associated with the `order` by looking at the database table. Anyone got a clue about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have configured the `mappedBy` incoretly.. the other way round actually.

So you should have it like this:

Order:

```
@Entity(name = "orders") // Select * from order order by... NO!
public class Order {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = EAGER)
    private List<OrderEntity> orderEntities = new ArrayList<>();
```

Product:

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<OrderEntity> orderEntity;
```